# Ubuntu16.04 Gnome cannot save setting

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I got a problem after an system upgrade.I chosen some config yes. And here,I lost my desktop icon.I cannot change system settings such as key map shutcut.I cannot neither change themes nor enable extensions with gnome-tweak-tool.
I've tried reinstall gnome and uninstall unity,but it's useless.
my gnome version is 3.18.
Dose any body have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why,but I fix it by add `export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/`
  to /ext/profile